# Why is keyword 's' giving me an error?

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string

I have the following method which gives me an error when the word is "sk" but not when it is "ks". These keywords are coming from the arrPunjabi.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at StringTes.main(StringTes.java:51)

HashSet<String> all = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] arrPunjabi = {"d b a b s k s", "d t r p n d k h"};
    String[] arrGurmukhi = {"fMfauiq bMdn Aink bwr srb klw smrQ ]", "foln qy rwKhu pRBU nwnk dy kir hQ ]1]"};
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    String word = "sk";
    char[] wordArr = word.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i< arrPunjabi.length;i++){
        String[] words = arrPunjabi[i].split("\\s+");
        //word[] = {d, b, a, b, s, k, s};
     if (word.length() == 2){
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
                if(words[j].startsWith(""+wordArr[0]) && words[j+1].startsWith(""+wordArr[1])){   //this is where I am getting an error.
                    arr.add(arrGurmukhi[i]);
                    all.addAll(arr);
                    arr.clear();
                    arr.addAll(all);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(arr);
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? What line causes it?

Comment: I have mentioned it in my comments

Comment: No you don't. You never state what the error is. It's a moot issue now, since Josh has identified it and solved it (please accept his answer), but next time, please give us the full error message, please give us both a comment in the code and a detailed description of the error in your question text.

Answer (score 6):

Look at your loop condition; it loops under the condition that `j < words.length`. You are trying to access an element at `j+1`, causing it to throw an `IndexArrayOutOfBoundsException`. You either need to change `j < words.length` to `j < words.length-1` or use an alternate method for whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: No, that's not an issue. Cause when I change in my arrPunjabi from "s k s" to "d k s" and my word is "dk" That works then but not when it's "dk"

Comment: Trying to access an element from an array using an invalid index isn't an issue?

Comment: Never mind. I see what you were trying to say. I got it now. Thanks a lot for your help! :)